# MySQL using UPDATE ,SET,REPLACE string with UTF-8 format

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I have this piece of code below and it's working fine, the issues is that when it goes up if I use bulgarian characters everything comes out like Ð¡Ñ‚Ñ€Ð°Ð½Ð°Ñ‚Ð° Ð½Ð° Ñ‡ÑƒÐ´ÐµÑÐ°Ñ‚Ð

But when I add bulgarian stuff from the admin menu (Opencart) display in Bulgarian.

The Database table `'name'` is in utf8_general_ci.

```
   <?php
include 'config.php';
$servername = DB_HOSTNAME;
$username = DB_USERNAME;
$password = DB_PASSWORD;
$dbname = DB_DATABASE;
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "UPDATE product_description SET name = REPLACE(name, 'The amazing spiderman Phone', 'Страната на чудесата')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: set $conn->set_charset("utf8"); and check

Comment: so what do u want ?\

Comment: Duplicate see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391140/mysql-bulgarian-languages-character-set

Comment: Thanks that did the work perfectly.

Kinda new to stackoverflow how to check your answer as the right one?